# Use Intermediate Value Theorem to show that there is a root of the given equation

Tags: calculus

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcScv.png)
[My Work So Far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyhT9.jpg)

Can someone double check this for me? I was going over the answer with another friend and his answer was the opposite of mine. Not sure which one I should go for.

Comment: Looks correct. May be he defined $f(x)=\ln x - e^{-x}$?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I can probably explain the downvote - rather than posting a picture, it is better to type up the maths here. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

What you did is fine. You just forgot to add that $\frac1e>0$ and that $e^{-e}-1<0$ (since $x<0\implies e^x<1$).

Answer (score 0):

I add there is at least one root . To prove there is one and only one root, you must show that $f$ such that $f(x)=\ln x-e^{-x}$ is monotonic.